# Running a js function while opened embed frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I embed video from pornsite with this code

```
<iframe src="http://www.pornhub.com/embed/1072378305" id="video-frame" frameborder="0" height="450" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

and it creates iframe with vide of course.

I also have this function in my script

```
$(window).keyup(function(event) {
   alert('hello');
});
```

this function works fine, **BUT when I maximize the video** with the iframe and **THEN** press any key on keyboard it does nothing, the keyup event doesn't work.

Any idea what should I do, to be able to listen pressing a keyboard when video iframe is maximized.

Thank you very much for any help.